# develop portable customisation for fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I need to customise fiddler to intercept the response to specific website to encrypt it.
However, I do not want it to be desktop application.  Can I make it as web based??

I need it to be portable, whenever user access this website he does not need to install this extension on each machine he use it to encrypt the response before send it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you're pretty confused about how the web works. The best way to encrypt requests to a website is to use HTTPS. Trying to "roll your own" encryption is a terrible idea.

Comment: What I want is to find approach to intercept the response to untrustable website 'such as data store in cloud' to encrypt it by myself . I found some people customising fiddler but the limitation is the mobility where they need to install the application in each machine they want to use the website from it.

Answer (score 0):

The web security model is such that you can't have one website (A) that gets access to another website's data (B), unless the target site (B) participates explicitly in the process and allows access by (A). Using a browser extension or Fiddler is a way to circumvent the web security model.

Comment: Thank you for your helping. Is their a possibility to consider a mobility?